# How to redirect all subpage to its main page?

Tags: apache2, redirect, .htaccess

I have migrated a static site to WordPress, now I need to redirect its pages, I have many URLs those will go one page, I can redirect one by one but those are many so I need a redirect rule that works for all.

For example, I have URLs like this

```
example.com/main-page/sub-page1/sub-page2/subpage3/
example.com/main-page/sub-page11/sub-page21/
example.com/main-page/sub-page5/sub-page25/subpage3/something.htm
example.com/main-page/sub-page1/
```

Now I want all subpages after /main-page/ will go example.com/main-page/

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/main-page/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/main-page/ [R=302,NC,L]
```